# Multiple values in typeahead

Tags: php, jquery, typeahead

I'm trying to get data from multiple tables and then show it is one under the input field. It currently just overlaps each other. I have a PHP file for users and one for companies.

**The JQuery:**

```
     var companies = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '_companies?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    var users = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('username'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '_users?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    companies.initialize();
    users.initialize();

    $('#username').typeahead({

        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 2
    }, {
        name: 'companies',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: companies.ttAdapter()
    });

    $('#username').typeahead({

        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 2
    }, {
        name: 'users',
        displayKey: 'username',
        source: users.ttAdapter()
    });
```

**_users.php:**

```
<?php

require_once '../core/init.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(!isset($_GET['query'])) {
    echo json_encode([]);
    exit();
}

$u = new User();

$uData = $u->autoComplete(escape($_GET['query']));
$uData = $u->data();

echo json_encode($uData);
```

`_companies.php` is a similar file. Uses the almost the same code.

**The HTML input field:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Aan:</label><br />
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" id="username" name="gebruikersnaam" value="<?php echo Input::get('gebruikersnaam'); ?>" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

**What it currently looks like:**

[image: Current field view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe it's because you initialize typeahead twice? Try to do something like this:

```
$('#username').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2
}, {
    name: 'companies',
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: companies.ttAdapter()
}, {
    name: 'users',
    displayKey: 'username',
    source: users.ttAdapter()
});
```